# Send keystrokes to TextBox

Tags: c#

I have a derived TextBox where I intercept the userinput to manipulate it. However I have to preserve the original typed input. So my idea was to hold an inner TextBox within my derived class and send the user's input to that TextBox before manipulating it.

The reason for this approach is that I do not want to take care of all this special actions like: typing something, ctrl+a, [del], type something else, [backspace] and so on ...

However I do not know how to send a single keystroke (keycode, ascii, char) to a TextBox. Maybe you have another idea without an inner TextBox at all? Thank you!

Comment: What kind of functionality are you trying to achieve by doing this? Isn't the password textbox doing things you want?

Comment: Yes, you are right - basically I want to create a password control, but within a DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl. Fortunatly - thanks for your comment - I see, that there is a PasswordChar-property, too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could just let the inner text box have keyboard focus and handle the input. Then you could handle its [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(loband).aspx)/[`KeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(loband).aspx)/[`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(loband).aspx) events in your container class to "intercept" the input.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use keyboard-level manipulation because there are ways to change the text without the keyboard (in particular, with copy, cut, and paste).  Why not use the Text property to get the text from the original textbox and then just save that?

Comment: That's exactly the reason why I thought of an inner TextBox that behaves like the original one - ctrl+a, ctrl+c, ctrl+v and so on would be handeled correctly. I am missing a counterpart to the methods like OnKeyPress() - this counterpart should accept a KeyPressEventArg maybe ProcessKeyChar()?

Comment: A user can do copy, cut, and paste without touching the keyboard.